# Django, CORS, CSRF - am I doing it right?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, cors, csrf, django-cors-headers

My setup (local) is the following:

- Vue.js running on localhost:8080 (npm run serve)
- REST API built with Django running on localhost:8000 (./manage-py runserver)

In order to enable this to work I've made the following additions:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
...
'localhost',
'localhost:8000',
'localhost:8080',
]

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ...
]

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'localhost:8080',
    'localhost:8000',
)

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

from corsheaders.defaults import default_headers

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = default_headers + (
    'credentials',
)
```

One of my API functions:

```
@ensure_csrf_cookie
def try_login(request):
  # this is just to get the initial CSRF token:
  if request.method == "GET" or request.method == "OPTIONS":
    return JsonResponse({'status': 'ok'}) 
  # else, an actual login request:
  else:
    data = JSONParser().parse(request)
    user = authenticate(request, username=data['user'] , password=data['pass'])
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        return JsonResponse({'login_succ': 'ok'});
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'login_succ': 'fail'});
```

Finally, in Vue:

```
api: function(endpoint, method, data) {
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('content-type', 'application/json');
    if (... this is not the first request ever ...) 
    {
      csrftoken = document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)csrftoken\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1");
      headers.append('X-CSRFToken', csrftoken);
    }
    method = method || 'GET';
    var config = {
      method: method,
      body: data !== undefined ? JSON.stringify(data) : null,
      headers: headers,
    };

    config['credentials'] = 'include';

    return fetch(endpoint, config)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .catch((error) => { console.log(...); });
  },

trylogin: function() {
    // initial request: just to get the CSRF token
    this.api(".../login/", "GET").then(
      response => {
          this.api(".../login/", "POST", {'username': ..., 'password': ...}  ).then(
          response => {
            if ("login_succ" in response && res["login_succ"] == "ok")
            {}  // user is logged in
          }
        );
      }
    );

   }
```

What happens now, afaiu, is that my initial API request (which **does not** have to be pointed to the endpoint equal to the subsequent POST request, right?) gets the CSRF token as a cookie. Every subsequent request reads this cookie and sets the *X-CSRFToken* header. The cookie itself is also being sent in the subsequent requests. I do not understand why is the token needed in both places.

Is this approach correct? Is everything I've done necessary? (Are there redundant parts?) I'm especially interested in the way that I should acquire the token in the first place, and in general with the token's lifecycle.

Thank you.

Comment: are you getting errors on the server or in the browser?

Comment: @RudolfOlah, I'm not getting errors, but I'm still not sure if I'm doing everything correctly.